# Enclosing Shortcode not working in a Template

Tags: shortcode, page-template

I've use the following code for an enclosing shortcode and it works perfectly in the posts.

```
function date_code($attr, $content)
{
   return '<h3>' . $content . '</h3>';
}

add_shortcode('datecode', 'date_code');
```

But when I try to use it in a page template using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode it's not working.

I've use the following code in my template:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[datecode]' . $content . '[/datecode]' );
```

**Please help me since the non-enclosing shortcode works fine with do_shortcode.** And, I'm ignorant with regards to using enclosing shortcode in a page template.

I want to display the shortcode in the page template like in the posts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above code works perfectly for me. What are you setting as `$content` when you use `do_shortcode`?

Comment: where is `$content` defined in your template? how does 'it is not working' show?

Comment: @Stephen Harris: I'm not setting anything as $content. I don't know how to display the shortcode inside a page template. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcode wraps something in header tags. For the shortcode to work you need to provide that something.

Your code above works fine, you just need to set `$content='My header text';` prior to echoing the shortcode in your template. currently you are not wrapping anything in the header tags.

But you shouldn't need to use a shortcode for wrapping in HTML tags- just use the html:

```
<h1> My header text</h1>
```

rather than

```
   <?php echo do_shortcode( '[datecode]' .'My header text'. '[/datecode]' ); ?>
```

Comment: Not working with your tip. Seems to be like that I've missed somewhere. I've tried by removing the <h3> tag, but in vain. Should I modify the function itself ?

Comment: The `do_shortcode` code in my answer works fine with the shortcode you've defined in your question. It takes the 'My header text' and wraps in `<h3>` tags. If you are still having problems, edit your question to include what are doing in your template.

Comment: I don't want to change the original function. Please guide me how to display the shortcode in a template with the help of a source code example.

Comment: If you put the function and the `add_shortcode` from your question into your `functions.php` file and then use the `do_shortcode` in my answer in a template it works fine. If it doesn't work for you, you'll need to post your code for me to see what you are doing wrong.